# $A \cup B \cup C = (A - B) \cup (B - C) \cup (C - A) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am using the fact that $X = (X - Y) \cup (X \cap Y)$

So far I've got:

$$A \cup B \cup C = (A - B) \cup (B - C) \cup (C - A) \cup (A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)\cup(C\cap A)$$

This is almost done, except now I have to deal with $(A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)\cup(C\cap A)$. How can I use this to get to $A\cap B \cap C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, this approach won't work, as $A\cap B$ alone is possibly greater than $A\cap B \cap C$. I like to always get rid of minus using $A-B=A\cap B^c$. Now it is much easier as you can use distributivity and De Morgan's law:
$$(A-B)\cup (B-C)\cup (C-A)=(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap A^c)=$$
$$(A\cup B\cup C)\cap (A\cup B\cup A^c)\cap (A\cup C^c\cup C)\cap (A\cup C^c\cup A^c)\cap (B^c\cup B\cup C)\cap (B^c\cup B\cup A^c)\cap (B^c\cup C^c\cup C)\cap (B^c\cup C^c\cup A^c)$$
While it looks overwhelming, it actually simplifies to:
$$(A\cup B\cup C)\cap (B^c\cup C^c\cup A^c)=(A\cup B\cup C)\cap (B\cap C\cap A)^c$$
And now we can go back to set-minus representation:
$$(A\cup B\cup C)\cap (B\cap C\cap A)^c=(A\cup B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C\cap A)$$
So finally:
$$(A-B)\cup (B-C)\cup (C-A)\cup (A\cap B \cap C)=A\cup B\cup C$$
While such approach is always possible, it isn't the shortest one.

Comment: Could you explain how you went from $(A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap C^c) \cup (C \cap A^c)$ to the overwhelming part after it? What facts did you use to get to there?

Comment: Distributive property https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_properties_of_set_algebra.
It is analogous to elimination of braces in arithmetic expression $(t+u)*(v+w)*(x+y)$.

Comment: Ah of course. I just got lost in the details to not see it. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, what allows you to "add" $(A \cap B \cap C)$" to the LHS to complete the proof?

Comment: My bad, I'm bad at explaining :). Take look at LHS of my first equation - it is $(A-B)\cup (B-C)\cup (C-A)$. I just dropped $(A\cap B \cap C)$ to shorten equations. It could've been assigned to some temporary auxiliary $X$ for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Venn Diagrams are great! Here is a visual "proof" of your statement:

[image]
Note that all regions are mutually exclusive (i,e, an element in $A - B$ cannot be in $B - C$, and an element in $C - A$ cannot be in $A\cap B\cap C$). Also note that an element of $A\cup B\cup C$ must be in at least one of these regions.

Comment: For intuitive understanding purposes this is probably the best "proof".

Answer (score 0):

You won't get $A\cap B\cap C$ in a natural way from this union.

I suggest instead to classify the elements of $A\cup B\cup C$ by the number of sets in $\{A,B,C\}$ to which it belongs, and to show that if it belongs to a single set, or to two of them, but not all, then it is already in $A\setminus B$, or in $B\setminus C$ or in $C\setminus A$.

Comment: Would this be proof by cases? That's very interesting. Would I then just show that every permutation of $x \in A$, $x \in B$ and $x \in C$ is valid?

Comment: Sort of. The main job is to try to have the shortest possible phrasing for the proof. You may use that $A\cup B\cup C$ is symmetric in $A, B,C$, so that you only have two cases really to examine  for an element which is not in the intersection of all: it is either in a single set or in two, and use the symmetry.